# Why react not render false

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I read documentation here https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/false-in-jsx.html, but still can't understand, why if I type 
`ReactDOM.render(<div>{false}</div>, mountNode);`
I nothing received?

Comment: You don't receive nothing it is a div with nothing inside of it because you are evaluating false inside of it...

Comment: Where is you domContainerNode?

Comment: @ajmajmajma right I am understand, If I call `<div>{false}</div>` ReactJS received an empty div?

Comment: @Techidiot I consider an example given in documentation, and there is `ReactDOM.render(<div>{false}</div>, mountNode);`

Comment: But the code your post shows doesn't have mountNode

Comment: @Techidiot I edit post

Comment: @user3600840 What would you like it to render?

Comment: @Cosmin Ababei  I can't understand, why if I type <div>{false}</div>, I nothing received

Comment: In jsx, whatever you put inside {} is just evaluated, so you have that div and inside you are just evaluating false, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @ajmajmajma I suppose, that it should return **false**, like if I write for example `ReactDOM.render(<div id={false} />, mountNode);`

Comment: Those are special cases, because in id and value for example you will want to evaluate to a string.

Answer (score 6):

**To enable syntactic sugar for the ternary operator**.

---

Now you can write the much more elegant

```
<div> { !!price && price } </div>
```

Instead of

```
 <div> { !!price ? price : null } </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It literally says in the documentation you have posted that it will render a div with no child

No child:

```
ReactDOM.render(<div>{false}</div>, mountNode);
```

The reason why this one doesn't render as the string "false" as a div child is to allow the more common use-case: `<div>{x > 1 && 'You have more than one item'}</div>`

[False in JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/false-in-jsx.html)